# Getting quote item data in abstract class

Tags: model, quoteitem

I'm creating an abstract class that is extending `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`.

When I run

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    Mage::log($item->getSku(),null,'test.log',true);
}
```

I get nothing in the logs about this. How can I get access to the items?

**Update**

Thanks to Amit's answer below I was able to find out how to get the sku for the order

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_collection');


foreach($orders as $order){
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` using it working

on frontend

but it **does not work on backend**.

For `backend magento use different model`

```
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')-.
```

**Better solution is below:**

```
$paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();

if ($paymentInfo instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment) {
        // used  for order object
     } else {
         $Quote = $paymentInfo->getQuote();
    // put your code  here  
        $Quote = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
         Mage::log($item->getSku(),null,'test.log',true);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. So in the conditional where you put 'used for order object', how would I be able to access the order item, like sku?

Comment: Ok I've seen your edit. My problem now is that $paymentInfo is instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment, so it goes into the 'used for order object' part.

Comment: let me check...